# How to change the container color of a pickerInput element?

Tags: html, r, shiny

When i move a pickerInput element to the left using margin-left, there is a white space appearing which i can not get to the same color as the rest of page.

I have tried many variation of css configurations but noting works

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    HTML(
      "

body{
 background-color: grey;
}


          button, select {
          margin-left: 90px;
          background-color: darkgrey;
        }



  ")
  ),





  fluidRow(
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "select1",
      label = "pickerInput",
      choices = c(3, 4, 8, 5, 2, 6, 7),
      options = list(title = "Please Select Desired Number")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The background should be like the rest of the page in gray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be better to wrap the `pickerInput` inside a div tag.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style("body{background:grey}")),
    fluidRow(
        tags$div(
            style = "margin-left:90px",
            pickerInput(
                inputId = "select1",
                label = "pickerInput",
                choices = c(3, 4, 8, 5, 2, 6, 7),
                options = list(title = "Please Select Desired Number")
            )
        )
    )
)
```

If you need to apply this style to multiple `pickerInput`, it's still better to use `div` tags to wrap the `pickerInput`, and use class for CSS selector.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            "body{
                background:grey;
            }
            .ident-picker {
                margin-left:90px;
            }"
        )
    ),
    fluidRow(
        tags$div(
            class = "ident-picker",
            pickerInput(
                inputId = "select1",
                label = "pickerInput",
                choices = c(3, 4, 8, 5, 2, 6, 7),
                options = list(title = "Please Select Desired Number")
            )
        )
    ),
    fluidRow(
        tags$div(
            class = "ident-picker",
            pickerInput(
                inputId = "select2",
                label = "pickerInput2",
                choices = letters,
                options = list(title = "Please Select Desired characters")
            )
        )
    )

)
```

[image]

Also, you can write a wrapper function on existing UI functions

```r
library(shiny)
library(rlang)

actionButtonPretty <- function(inputId, label){
    actionButton(inputId, label, style="color: white; background-color:#003c69; border-color: #003c69; ")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButtonPretty("button1","Pretty Button 1"),
    actionButtonPretty("button2","Pretty Button 2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much. very helpful. It works. Is there also a way to set a golobal style for the actionButton? I mean one can change the style for each like this


**`actionButton("dofloris", "server", 
style="color: white; background-color:#003c69; border-color: #003c69; ")`**


but is there a way to define a style for all actionButton type button and not one by one.

Comment: I already edited my answer based on your follow-up question: One way is to write a wrapper function: `actionButtonPretty <- function(inputId, label){
    actionButton(inputId, label, style="color: white; background-color:#003c69; border-color: #003c69; ")
}
`

Comment: @yusuzech: how do you change the background color of the `pickerInput` box itself? I tried your trick but `pickerInput` does not support `style` as an argurment. Thanks!